# I need help performing a DZPN analysis.

Tags: functional-analysis

Given $f(x,y)=\ln(x^2-y^2)$, perform a $DZPN$ analysis.

I have $D(f):{(x,y):x^2-y^2}=?$

$Z(f):{(x,y):x^2-y^2=1}$

$P(f):{(x,y):x^2-y^2>1}$

$N(f):{(x,y):0<x^2-y^2<1}$

I cannot find the Domain and would like to receive confirmation that the answers I have are currently correct.

Comment: $D_f=\{(x, y)|x^2-y^2>0\}$

Comment: is everything else correct?

Comment: @Takhteh_pareh is everything correct?

Comment: I don't know, what $Z(f), P(f), N(f)$ means.